# Simple IIS URL Rewrite

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

Simple question. I need to redirect all http 80 and https 443 requests on a specific subdomain URL to an alternative SSL port https 444.

Example: http://sub.corp.com --> https://sub.corp.com:444
Example: https://sub.corp.com --> https://sub.corp.com:444

I only wish to use IIS 7.5 URL Rewrite module.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following URL rewrite rule should do what you want:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to port 444" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^ON$" negate="true" />
                <add input="{SERVER_PORT}" pattern="^444$" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://sub.corp.com:444/{R:0}" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

It redirects to https://sub.corp.com:444 whenever HTTPS is not ON or when the port number is not 444. The site should have bindings to port 80 (with HTTP), 443 (with HTTPS for standards SSL) en 444 (with HTTPS) for this to work.

Comment: Thanks. There is also the scenario where there are multiple subdomains, sub1 and sub2. The redirect needs to know which to rewrite as.

Comment: @Marco Miltenburg Can I kindly ask Marco why you didnt use <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$"  /> are these not the same or am I missing something.

Comment: @TinoMclaren Yes it's the same.

Answer (score 1):

Marco's solutions works fine, in case somebody is wondering how to apply this in IIS.
you add this to the **web.config** file. If you create a Virtual Directory in IIS the selected physical folder will have a web.config created.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect to port 50443" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^ON$" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{SERVER_PORT}" pattern="^50443$" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}:50443/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: it seems you have good command over iis rewrite rule. i am new in this area. if possible please have a look at my post and share your valuable answer. my post link is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47474674/iis-rewrite-rule-change-my-current-aspx-page-hyperlink-href-wrong-way